# What are some cool JQuery/CSS3 effects like Google's "Barrel Roll"

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

For those of you who do not know how the "Barrel roll" is done, here's the code:

```
<style>
.barrel_roll {
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 4s ease;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 4s ease;
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -o-transition: -o-transform 4s ease;
    -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transition: transform 4s ease;
    transform: rotate(360deg);
}  
</style>
<script>
function barrel_roll() {
    $('body').addClass('barrel_roll');
  setTimeout("$('body').removeClass('barrel_roll')", 4000);
}
</script>
```

My question is, what are some other cool effects that can be done using Javascript and/or CSS?

Comment: Please.. ***NEVER*** pass a string to setTimeout, pass a function instead: `setTimeout(function() { $('body').removeClass('barrel_roll'); }, 4000);`

Comment: are you having trouble with the barrel roll? do you have an issue with some other effect you are trying to use? Are you looking for the documentation for some other specific effect? This site isn't so much meant for "help me find something cool" questions as much as "I'm trying to do X and am having problem Y"

Comment: funnily enough , although the question is not constructive , i found the code pretty useful. Its good that closed questions still remain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Highlight elements  - http://www.keyframesandcode.com/resources/javascript/jQuery/demos/highlight-demo.html

Textarea auto-complete - http://www.amirharel.com/2011/03/07/implementing-autocomplete-jquery-plugin-for-textarea/

Featured Content Slider - http://webdeveloperplus.com/jquery/featured-content-slider-using-jquery-ui/

10 Photo Galleries and Sliders - http://www.queness.com/post/222/10-jquery-photo-gallery-and-slider-plugins

Scrollable - New Wave UI Design - http://flowplayer.org/tools/scrollable/

50 CSS3 Animations - http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/50-awesome-css3-animations/

nth-child everywhere (easy table zebra striping). - http://verboselogging.com/2010/01/17/making-nth-child-work-everywhere